# Drawing circular set with bowed partitions using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

The following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \a in {120,250,310}
{
\draw (-1,.5) -- (\a:4cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

draws the a partitioned set into three subsets of various sizes:

[image]

The first question is: how to fill these three different regios with different colours? I tried with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \a in {120,250,310}
{
\draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (-1,.5) -- (\a:4cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I still obtainend the same figure.

Moreover, I would like to replace the three straight lines used for the partition with curves. Then I used:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \a in {120,250,310}
{
\draw (-1,.5) to[out=135, in=315] (\a:4cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I obtained:

[image]

which seems to have problems in the intersection of the three curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I got this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=red!30] circle (3cm);
\draw[fill=blue!30] (160:3cm)-- (160:2cm) to [curve through={(159:1cm) (30:0.5cm)}] (35:3cm) arc (35:160:3cm)--cycle;
\draw[fill=green] (160:3cm)-- (160:2cm) to [curve through={(165:1cm) (270:0.5cm)}] (275:3cm) arc (275:160:3cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know they are not curves, but they look like curves ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any clipping to achieve that but you have to be careful with your `in and out`s.

[image: V1]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{3}
        \coordinate (A) at (-1,.5);
        \fill[cyan] (A) to [out=135,in=45] (250:\r cm) arc (250:120:\r) to [out=-110,in=135] (A) ;
        \fill[orange] (A) to [out=135,in=45] (250:\r cm) arc (250:310:\r) to [out=135,in=-45] (A) ;
        \fill[pink] (A) to [out=-45,in=135] (310:\r cm) arc (-50:120:\r) to [out=-110,in=135] (A) ;
        %\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A little change in the parameters:

[image: v2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{3}
        \coordinate (A) at (-1,.5);
        \fill[cyan] (A) to [out=135,in=45] (250:\r cm) arc (250:120:\r) to [out=-110,in=135] (A) ;
        \fill[orange] (A) to [out=135,in=45] (250:\r cm) arc (250:310:\r) to [out=90,in=-45] (A) ;
        \fill[pink] (A) to [out=-45,in=90] (310:\r cm) arc (-50:120:\r) to [out=-110,in=135] (A) ;
        %\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

And just to let you know that there's no clipping needed and that no shape is drawn upon another one, here's a broken figure.

[image: broken figure]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{3}
        \coordinate (A) at (-1,.5);

        \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-10pt}]
            \fill[cyan] (A) to [out=135,in=45] (250:\r cm) arc (250:120:\r) to [out=-110,in=135] (A) ;
        \end{scope}
        \
        begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=-10pt}]
            \fill[orange] (A) to [out=135,in=45] (250:\r cm) arc (250:310:\r) to [out=90,in=-45] (A) ;
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=5pt,yshift=5pt}]
            \fill[pink] (A) to [out=-45,in=90] (310:\r cm) arc (-50:120:\r) to [out=-110,in=135] (A) ;
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An early response

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (3cm);

\draw[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (-1,.5) coordinate(a)-- (120:4cm) arc (120:60:4cm) -- (a);

\draw[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] (-1,.5) coordinate(a)-- (60:4cm) arc (60:-130:4cm) -- (a);
\draw[pattern=vertical lines,pattern color=purple] (-1,.5) coordinate(a)-- (-130:4cm) arc (-130:-240:4cm) -- (a);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to substitute straight lines with curves?